# How to compare two Objects as if Option Strict were Off

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET project (VB 2012, .NET Framework 4.5) where I need to compare two `Object`s for equality. Specifically, it's some COM Interop code that is dealing with ADO `Recordset` objects, and the `Bookmark` property of a `Recordset` is a COM `Variant`, which gets turned into an `Object` in VB.NET.

Currently, I have `Option Strict Off`, which lets me compare the `Object`s using the `=` operator. However, I'd like to turn `Option Strict On` for the file and just do the "lax" comparison in the few places where it's needed. The "Typeless Programming with Relational Comparison Operators" section of [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx) explains how VB implements comparisons between `Object`s with `Option Strict Off`, and I can write a function to do the same thing. But it seems likely that there's already an implementation of the "lax" comparison somewhere in .NET, and I don't want to re-implement the wheel. Is there something that will already do what I want?

Comment: You can compare objects using the [Is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx) keyword.

Comment: @Bugs You _can_, but that doesn't do the same type of comparison as the = operator when Option Strict is Off. `Is` compares two Object references, but I want to compare two values, e.g., two `Integer`s that are stored in a variable of type Object.

Comment: Ah sorry I see. Yes ignore me then. I was comparing objects, not properties on an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the IL generated, when `Option Strict Off` applies `objectA = objectB` is compiled to

`Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.ConditionalCompareObjectEqual(objectA ,objectB ,False)`

Thus you should be able to use that function directly when you know both types are coming in as object.

You will of course need to test.